# Add new button for custom made order status to order view in Magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, button, admin, status

I have 3 stages of order hold. One is the default hold, second one is the reason of hold its `Stock Awaited(hold_stock_awaited)` and other is `Stock Clearance(hold_stock_clearance)`.
I would like to have a button just like the hold button that when clicked can put my order direct to the custom made hold status.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add an button like hold on order page you need to over write files app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php by using modules

```
 <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>

 public function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton('your_button_id', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('xxx')->__('Some action'),
             'onclick'   => "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('*/*/Youbuttonfunction')."')",/* refere ref1*/
            'class'     => 'go'
        ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    }

ref1: you need to add Youbuttonfunction function in module controller perform your action and return back to order url
```

You can get refference from  below link [add-button-in-any-admin-page](http://www.tutorial-portal.com/tutorial/23/add-button-in-any-admin-page)

Comment: how can i get this button to set order status to the status i made?

Comment: you have to pass value of order status to function and then can perform action you want. If you add   $this->_addButton('your_button_id', array( in constructor you will get button on view page but to work you need to write function